# Why is this part of the mesh following this bone even when I paint over it with a fully-weighted Subtract brush in Weight Paint mode?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, vertex-groups, vertex-weights, weight-paint-mode

On Blender 2.93

I'd rather not post the .blend as this model is meant to stay private. The strand of hair that moves with the antenna's bone in this screencap really says it all.

[image]

It was exported as a VRM from VRoid Studio and then imported into Blender using the VRM Import plugin. In the rest mode, i.e. before I pose any bones, that strand you're seeing is part of the root of that antenna, which extends down a bit inside of the head. On both sides with both antennae, VRoid has auto-generated a weight paint configuration in which those strands move with the outer 3rd bone of the chain. I've gone into Weight Paint mode and made sure that entire strand is all blue, but it still happens. My guess is maybe one single vertex is still weighted and inexplicably ignoring my brush when I Subtract paint. I've already spent hours trying to mess with Vertex Groups and weights, but I can't get anywhere because the Vertex Weight slider in Edit mode doesn't do anything (bug?).

Comment: You could delete the character except the hair so that we can try, and share the file here: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Blender decided to also take a dump on the entire model and throw off all the weight painting. It's been spewed all over the place. This model now moves like an eldritch horror. I have no clue why it happened except if maybe that stupid Vertex Weight slider in the Vertex Groups menu is so bugged that it broke everything just from my trying to use it once on one single group of just a few vertices.

It's going to be a bit before I can get back to this issue. I have to start all the way over from the VRM file now.